# Unsupported Operand Types? python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a small-scale text based game. I am having trouble when validating user input. If possible, I would love for any suggestions on cleaning this up, or fixing the unsupported operand type error.

Thanks in advance.

```
def getPlayerName():
    playerName = input("What is your name?")
    print("\nHello, " + playerName + ".") 

def getPlayerAge():
    playerAge = input("What is your age?")

def getPlayerJob():
    print("The current available occupations are as follows:\nA: Farmer,\nB: Soldier,\nC: Scientist")
    playerJob = input("So which do you choose?")

    if (playerJob == "A" | "a" | "Farmer" | "farmer"):
        playerHp = 25
        playerDamage = 15
        playerPerception = 20

    elif (playerJob == "B" | "b" | "Soldier" | "soldier"):
        playerHp = 30
        playerDamage = 20
        playerPerception = 10

    elif (playerJob == "C" | "c" | "Scientist" | "scientist"):
        playerHp = 20
        playerDamage = 10
        playerPerception = 30


class player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, job, hp, damage, perception):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.job = job

            self.hp = hp
            self.damage = damage
            self.perception = perception
```

Comment: What's the trouble? Are you getting an error? Or do you not know how to validate user input?

Comment: | is not valid syntax in python, unless you are doing set unions, then ignore me.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid syntax in python:

```
playerJob == "A" | "a" | "Farmer" | "farmer"):
```

What you want it either

```
if playerJob == 'a' or playerJob =='A' or playerJob == 'Farmer' ect

#OR MORE READABLE
if playerJob in ('a', 'A, 'Farmer', 'farmer'):
```

I have cleaned your code up. I would advice you to move learn the basic syntax in python before moving on. Hope this helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, job, hp, damage, perception):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.job = job

            self.hp = hp
            self.damage = damage
            self.perception = perception

# you need a function to send objects that controls the main 
# flow of your program - main()
def main():
    name = getPlayerName()
    age = getPlayerAge()
    job, hp, damage, perception = getPlayerJob()
    #use the gathered variables to make your class
    player_object = Player(
                        name, age,
                        job, hp,
                        damage, perception
                        )

def getPlayerName():
    playerName = input("What is your name?")
    print("\nHello, " + playerName + ".") 
    return playerName  # return back to main

def getPlayerAge():
    playerAge = input("What is your age?")
    return playerAge  # return back to main

def getPlayerJob():
    print("The current available occupations are as follows:\n \
            A: Farmer,\nB: Soldier,\nC: Scientist")

    player.job = input("So which do you choose?")

    if playerJob in ( "A", "a", "Farmer", "farmer"):
        playerHp = 25
        playerDamage = 15
        playerPerception = 20
    elif player.Job in ("B", "b", "Soldier", "soldier"):
        playerHp = 30
        playerDamage = 20
        playerPerception = 10
    elif (player.Job in ("C", "c", "Scientist", "scientist"):
        playerHp = 20
        playerDamage = 10
        playerPerception = 30
    else:
        print("invalid selection try again:")
        getPlayerJob()

    return (job, playerHp, 
            playerDamage, playerPerception) # return all 4 values back to main in a single tuple


main()
```